# Need workaround for limit in Django mysql query

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

This line does not work:

```
specific_info = Special.objects.filter(specialid=pk).order_by('description')[:1]
```

This is the error that I get after switching from SQLite to MYSQL:

```
(1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")
```

EDIT: Here are my database settings for MYSQL:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': "password",
        'HOST': "",
        'PORT': "",
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the full view:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Special
    template_name = "special.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['special_info'] = Special.objects.filter(object__name=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by('thing')[:3]
        return context
```

Is there a workaround to do limits in Django with a MYSQL Database?

Comment: How did you configure MySQL?

Comment: @Willem, with pip3 install mysqlclient, localhost, mysqlworkbench. Are you looking for something specific?

Comment: how did you change the `settings.py`?

Comment: Added my database settings that I changed when I went from SQLite to MySQL.

Comment: The error says this is a subquery. Show the full query.

Comment: what version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Mysql version: Ver 8.0.18

Comment: @Daniel, that's the exact query, well I changed some of the names and stuff.

Comment: But you are not using a subquery here. Please show the whole function, then.

Comment: @Daniel, I added the full view that is breaking.